# Индексация header.php и footer.php

Tags: php, seo

В header.php и footer.php, в основном, находятся лого и главное меню. 
1) Закрывать их от индексации или не стоит? 
2) Если к ним обратиться напрямую, то они выведут информацию. Оставить так или куда перенаправить?

Comment: если вы нигде не будете размещать прямую ссылку на хэдэр и футер, то никто их и индексировать не будет.

Answer (score 1):

Зачем Вы собираетесь закрывать от индексации неотъемлемую часть всех страниц сайта? Да еще которая несет такую важную информацию. Закрывать надо системные файлы, в которых может храниться конфиденциальная информация и которая никак не поможет потенциальным посетителям при выборе в поисковике сайта для просмотра.

К тому же главное меню это для индекса точно лишним не будет. Да и кто знает, что Вы еще решите в хедер или футер запихнуть в будущем.